# PostgreSQL does not use GIN index for query

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

There is a query I use (there are OR blocks instead of large query_int because of better performance):

```
SELECT *
  FROM products AS p
WHERE ((
p.description && '{791,11705,22921,29515,36965,41021,47203,49459,54602,60499}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{62033,73399,75438,76195,78038,79370,82347,85446,85633,92320}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{94803,95210,103635,104413,110362,114901,115482,118053,144377,144592}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{162314,174062,177685,179717,181979,196348,201003,213047,223458,231169}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{237073,242931,244061,245314,246673,257988,260198,260664,263250,263957}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{271730,271817,273768,275097,279056,288771,289375,294934,304523,311319}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{312113,322217,322889,324356,325774,326251,338673,347436,347467,349276}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{352233,353920,356966,364539,364601,385678,394335,396345,404511,409874}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{423310,441817,445483,453401,460896,461693,462106,466680,474877,478839}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{484941,489442,489946,490523,490883,494463,496539,497198,503385,507944}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{512199,529380,529715,533907,534796,547913,551711,570389,574545,582169}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{586486,591756,597798,598733,601138,604477,606417,607399,609051,612431}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{627519,632265,642944,644396,652624,657323,660675,674114,680471,694340}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{696385,9709,41582,114552,279064,325285,342008,351284,628528,653153}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{656846,4316,10946,22093,24018,27702,33375,46878,65895,77003}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{95393,114783,118457,141371,150094,152895,162732,163157,163367,203877}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{210856,217923,241203,249221,253779,267201,272252,273653,278116,293802}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{295701,300599,302252,326873,358918,363728,383700,384585,424374,438758}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{447823,462266,470243,478988,480508,505702,509906,515737,564044,564152}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{571872,600824,608280,613624,646110,683957,689644,690990,47933,72118}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{254118,606448,642630,24354,133966,135193,286475,323715,343992,498832}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{499785,513456,618107,23542,27702,36048,69975,77818,98085,152727}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{171208,174406,186215,232375,277012,332626,369601,377201,503875,515732}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{519901,554731,586945,607591,20419,49442,69838,78897,83455,113858}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{134734,177867,193400,198939,201042,223104,242510,251089,270295,293557}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{328628,331289,396160,412975,458708,467312,473574,479129,507406,518668}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{522569,535130,611787,622383,635147,651673,664061,673324,691806,9709}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{41582,114552,279064,325285,342008,351284,628528,653153,656846,4316}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{10946,22093,24018,27702,33375,46878,65895,77003,95393,114783}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{118457,141371,150094,152895,162732,163157,163367,203877,210856,217923}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{241203,249221,253779,267201,272252,273653,278116,293802,295701,300599}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{302252,326873,358918,363728,383700,384585,424374,438758,447823,462266}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{470243,478988,480508,505702,509906,515737,564044,564152,571872,600824}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{608280,613624,646110,683957,689644,690990,427652,3396,5468,7071}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{11337,24554,28045,34050,34411,40342,49553,53281,56183,59036}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{59323,60385,67818,73546,78048,78495,83428,94363,96511,97090}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{105677,106812,110743,112667,116389,116389,121806,126249,126795,127471}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{129954,133423,134354,135154,138988,142529,147237,147802,149142,159859}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{160280,162042,162081,164552,165180,168690,171724,178865,186808,189770}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{191313,201193,203208,205776,212311,214999,217923,223830,223830,227350}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{230855,234335,235881,241681,244872,246560,246775,265180,270338,271211}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{274693,276959,279186,279393,289182,293996,294960,296449,298136,302773}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{302773,303951,305471,325206,330296,332384,336039,338215,339423,339516}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{341659,348117,349369,351365,351455,358337,371858,372312,373674,377031}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{377740,379629,384052,387662,395829,400033,400033,400840,402101,403762}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{404439,405690,408812,425888,428446,430709,432931,440178,445270,447227}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{448502,450834,453581,455663,464793,468955,471005,473375,475847,479237}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{480483,480483,489445,490632,491125,498006,503936,504569,508429,510547}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{516074,523310,530674,549031,551605,553582,554012,564755,567326,568098}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{570145,571846,576153,576696,578487,582018,582302,586374,587243,588502}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{589031,589574,595438,595678,597467,597556,605129,605494,611735,612377}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{612467,615794,617161,631021,632541,633465,640483,642678,664766,677814}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{678893,679507,689935,691793,693498,701870,44857,47744,149194,635437}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{678341,687444,9709,41582,114552,279064,325285,342008,351284,628528}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{653153,656846,4316,10946,22093,24018,27702,33375,46878,65895}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{77003,95393,114783,118457,141371,150094,152895,162732,163157,163367}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{203877,210856,217923,241203,249221,253779,267201,272252,273653,278116}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{293802,295701,300599,302252,326873,358918,363728,383700,384585,424374}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{438758,447823,462266,470243,478988,480508,505702,509906,515737,564044}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{564152,571872,600824,608280,613624,646110,683957,689644,690990,10651}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{19421,20884,26683,34732,74659,218430,228747,234480,319665,572147}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{669237,1421,3161,12427,19721,28154,31160,35426,37289,38423}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{42631,54527,57861,72521,73760,81702,83410,83651,91361,92351}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{93268,98744,103015,104011,112667,115648,121362,121362,123556,137986}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{140833,156239,157732,164100,164326,169961,183304,183641,185167,201635}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{206847,213795,214047,215641,218148,229596,242246,245073,250061,252552}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{253313,264925,265020,265469,267188,270462,272294,273558,274989,275584}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{277219,280289,287867,294551,301174,304102,312987,314320,316688,320693}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{323204,324561,324561,325586,330911,337556,341611,342303,343187,345029}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{347527,348614,357527,357574,359225,370530,376234,379821,393586,394888}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{398613,399253,410485,412016,416022,434669,445023,451774,453222,456413}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{458007,460434,464534,466956,471096,474085,477351,480873,488478,493273}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{499989,507214,509932,512565,518521,523187,525811,539965,542990,544503}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{549556,557349,558828,559533,560062,563538,576377,578254,581474,586154}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{590178,592106,592607,595291,602985,606274,608227,612767,630647,638911}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{651972,654823,655993,664629,670034,670034,674441,682640,682978,685971}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{691824,696822,702920,330909,9709,41582,114552,279064,325285,342008}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{351284,628528,653153,656846,4316,10946,22093,24018,27702,33375}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{46878,65895,77003,95393,114783,118457,141371,150094,152895,162732}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{163157,163367,203877,210856,217923,241203,249221,253779,267201,272252}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{273653,278116,293802,295701,300599,302252,326873,358918,363728,383700}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{384585,424374,438758,447823,462266,470243,478988,480508,505702,509906}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{515737,564044,564152,571872,600824,608280,613624,646110,683957,689644}' :: INT [] OR
p.description && '{690990}' :: INT []));
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE for query:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..89666.80 rows=207290 width=139) (actual time=2.431..6942.170 rows=76101 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on products p  (cost=0.00..67937.80 rows=86371 width=139) (actual time=0.586..6853.961 rows=25367 loops=3)
        Filter: ((description && '{791,11705,22921,29515,36965,41021,47203,49459,54602,60499}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{62033,73399,75438,76195,78038,79370,82347,85446,85633,92320}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{94803,95210,103635,104413,110362,114901,115482,118053,144377,144592}'::integer[]) OR ...
        Rows Removed by Filter: 61185
Planning time: 1.918 ms
Execution time: 6950.584 ms
```

and EXPLAIN ANALYZE with ENABLE_SEQSCAN = FALSE; option:

```
Gather  (cost=19139.18..107805.98 rows=207290 width=139) (actual time=512.903..571.331 rows=76101 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on products p  (cost=18139.18..86076.98 rows=86371 width=139) (actual time=502.441..517.985 rows=25367 loops=3)
        Recheck Cond: ((description && '{791,11705,22921,29515,36965,41021,47203,49459,54602,60499}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{62033,73399,75438,76195,78038,79370,82347,85446,85633,92320}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{94803,95210,103635,104413,110362,114901,115482,118053,144377,144592}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{162314,174062,177685,179717,181979,196348,201003,213047,223458,231169}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{237073,242931,244061,245314,246673,257988,260198,260664,263250,263957}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{271730,271817,273768,275097,279056,288771,289375,294934,304523,311319}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{312113,322217,322889,324356,325774,326251,338673,347436,347467,349276}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{352233,353920,356966,364539,364601,385678,394335,396345,404511,409874}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{423310,441817,445483,453401,460896,461693,462106,466680,474877,478839}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{484941,489442,489946,490523,490883,494463,496539,497198,503385,507944}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{512199,529380,529715,533907,534796,547913,551711,570389,574545,582169}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{586486,591756,597798,598733,601138,604477,606417,607399,609051,612431}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{627519,632265,642944,644396,652624,657323,660675,674114,680471,694340}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{696385,9709,41582,114552,279064,325285,342008,351284,628528,653153}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{656846,4316,10946,22093,24018,27702,33375,46878,65895,77003}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{95393,114783,118457,141371,150094,152895,162732,163157,163367,203877}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{210856,217923,241203,249221,253779,267201,272252,273653,278116,293802}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{295701,300599,302252,326873,358918,363728,383700,384585,424374,438758}'::integer[]) OR (description && '{447823,462266,470243,478988,480508,505702,509906,515737,564044,564152}'::integer[]) OR ...)
        Heap Blocks: exact=91
        ->  BitmapOr  (cost=18139.18..18139.18 rows=259656 width=0) (actual time=504.150..504.150 rows=0 loops=1)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_gin_index  (cost=0.00..157.01 rows=3869 width=0) (actual time=39.016..39.016 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (description && '{791,11705,22921,29515,36965,41021,47203,49459,54602,60499}'::integer[])
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_gin_index  (cost=0.00..157.01 rows=3869 width=0) (actual time=10.940..10.940 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (description && '{62033,73399,75438,76195,78038,79370,82347,85446,85633,92320}'::integer[])
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_gin_index  (cost=0.00..157.01 rows=3869 width=0) (actual time=10.610..10.610 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (description && '{94803,95210,103635,104413,110362,114901,115482,118053,144377,144592}'::integer[])
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_gin_index  (cost=0.00..157.01 rows=3869 width=0) (actual time=11.452..11.452 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (description && '{162314,174062,177685,179717,181979,196348,201003,213047,223458,231169}'::integer[])
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_gin_index  (cost=0.00..157.01 rows=3869 width=0) (actual time=3.429..3.429 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (description && '{237073,242931,244061,245314,246673,257988,260198,260664,263250,263957}'::integer[])
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_gin_index  (cost=0.00..157.01 rows=3869 width=0) (actual time=2.290..2.290 rows=0 loops=1)
                    ...
Planning time: 1.378 ms
Execution time: 581.867 ms
```

As you can see second query is much faster despite planned cost.
The query is part of larger query (as CTE), so I cannot disable sequencial scan for whole query.

There is a products column:

```
prepared_description INT4[]
```

And GIN index for it:

```
CREATE INDEX products_gin_index ON products USING GIN(description gin__int_ops);
```

Table has ~300 000 rows and on average 21.6 ints in description array

Is there any way to force using index on this query?

Comment: Did you run `analyze` on that table? Maybe you need more precise statistics for that column `ALTER TABLE products ALTER COLUMN  description SET STATISTICS 1000`

Comment: statistics slightly changed cost (increased cost with index and without) - problem still occurs.

Comment: Did estimated rows got closer to actual number? In those initial plans it seems like Postgres struggles to get correct estimates. Did you try to concat all those arrays you compare `description` to and do just one `&&`? Result will be the same.

Comment: result is even worse ;)

`Seq Scan on prepare_description pd  (cost=0.00..47381.70 rows=189000 width=139) (actual time=0.199..19112.194 rows=76101 loops=1)`